# Where exactly are spring beans used? Looking for help understanding spring beans in depth

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inversion-of-control, javabeans

I'm using spring MVC and was hoping to understand the concept a bit better. I have been through some videos, samples and the spring Beans/IoC documentation but it's still not completely clear. I understand the basic idea behind it, but not where / how it is used exactly.

Asumming the example below (from this [repo](https://github.com/Java-Techie-jt/springboot-webflux-demo/blob/main/src/main/java/com/javatechie/webflux/router/RouterConfig.java)) where is the Bean later used? What is done by Spring Container 'in the background'? I can't see it behing used again in the rest of the sample (within that repo). Maybe anyone could shed some light as wo where exactly this bean is being used and / or what happens in the background. Many thnaks.

```
@Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction(){
        return RouterFunctions.route()
                .GET("/router/customers",handler::loadCustomers)
                 // Some more routes
                .build();

    }
```

Comment: Are you asking about that specific bean or beans in general?

Comment: I could be any example, not just the one mentioned. But i was looking for a concrete example. The theory behind bean is somewhat understood, but not where exactly this one (or any specific case) is used again.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-special-bean-types

Answer (score -1):

Beans are just to model your scenario. When you are trying to write a java program means you are trying to solve a real world problem in software aspect. For that first you need to model the problem in the application domain. Beans help you out there.
Spring wire up the things loosely, I would say. things change often, Spring supports the change easily. If you strict the connections and combinations with Java, you have much hard work to do in a change.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).